# Хинт репутационного графика в профиле содержит непереведенную дату

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, репутация

В секции "Репутация" профиля при наведении курсора на график отображение даты не локализовано:

[image: sunday]

Comment: ...и, я б сказал, "репутация" не согласуется с числительным :)

Comment: @D-side двести пятнадцать репутаций?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ага, в атрибуте `title` часть с датой не была локализована как надо.

Я обновил её, будет видно после очередного релиза.