# Отображении даты с учетом национальных особенностей

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация

В недавнем [вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3847/%D0%A5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83) был исправлен момент с переводом. Однако помимо этого не помешало бы учесть национальные особенности при отображении даты. В текущем виде:

[image: дата]

порядок отображения не совсем корректен.

Comment: А нет ли возможности в JS показывать дату в нативном для данного компьютера формате, согласно настройкам пользователя?

Comment: @VladD формально наверное можно (не шарю в JS), но будет ли это правильным, если смена языка ОС станет влиять на контент сайта?

Comment: Хм. Хорошо подмечено. Хуже того, если я заглядываю на en.SO и ru.SO, у меня будет дата отображаться одинаково, что будет выглядеть странно по крайней мере на одном из языков. Вы правы, предложение снимается.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант (не только изменение порядка, но и формы):

> Воскресенье, 2 октября 2016 года