# Ещё одна дыра в локализации дат репутации

Tags: дефект, локализация, репутация

При выборе конкретного столбца (дня) графика репутации, отображаемая подробная информация содержит не локализованную дату.

Привет смежному [багу](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3847/%D0%A5%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83) и товарищу @Oded.

[image: репутация по дате]